# Why realloc error Thread 1: signal SIGABRT

Tags: c, malloc, realloc

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<sys/uio.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<fcntl.h>
#include<stdarg.h>


void debug(void);
char * string(const char * );
char * strcats(const char * ,const char * );
char * strspe(const char *, ...);
int isDir(const char *);

int main(void){
    debug();
    return 0;
}

void debug(void){
    char * str = "ssssss";
    str = string("abcdef");
    
    char * hello;
    hello = strspe(str,"hello","world","world","world","world","world","world","world","world","world","world","world","world","world","world","world","world","world","world","world","world","world","world","world","world","world","world","world","world","world","world","world","world","world","world","world","world","world","world","world","world","world","world","world","world","world",NULL);
    
    printf("hello: %s   ,Address: %p\n",hello,(char *)hello);
}

char * string(const char * str){
    return strcpy(malloc(strlen(str) * sizeof(char) + sizeof(char)),str);
}

char * strcats(const char * str1,const char * str2){
    int realSize = (int)strlen(str2) * sizeof(char) + (int)strlen(str1) * sizeof(char) + sizeof(char);
    str1 = realloc((char *)str1,realSize);
    strcat((char *)str1,str2);
    return (char *)str1;
}

char * strspe(const char * format, ...)
{
    va_list args;
    const char * argv;
    char * result = string(format);
    //free((char*)format);
    va_start(args, format);
    while((argv = va_arg(args,const char *)) && argv != NULL){
        strcats((char *)result,argv);
    }
    va_end(args);
    return result;
}

int isDir(const char *filename){
    return (access(filename, 0) == 0);
}
```

Here is a piece of C code ，that sometimes runs, sometimes doesn't run and gives an error Thread 1: signal SIGABRT.

> Debug (23028,0x1000ebe00) malloc: *** error for object 0x1007af200: pointer being realloc's d was not allocated
> Debug (23028,0x1000ebe00) malloc: *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug(23028,0x1000ebe00) malloc: *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug(23028,0x1000ebe00
> (lldb)

And focus the cursor on line 37：

```
str1 = realloc((char *)str1,realSize);
```

I can't solve the problem

Comment: `strcats((char *)result,argv);`: The `strcats` function returns the new pointer, but you don't use it.  Should be `result = strcats(result, argv)`.  The cast should not be needed.

Comment: We have no idea where line 37 is. Do we need to count lines in your snippet? Also, what did you find when you expected the crashdump?

Comment: Welcome to SO. There is problably some reason why `strcats` returns some value. What is your reason to ignore it after calling?

Comment: Also the first argument of `strcats` should not be `const`, because the memory at that address is modified (after `realloc` that memory is no longer valid).

Comment: Thanks. I think I should just clear my head and look at it again

Comment: Never have `array = realloc(array, newSize);` – if re-allocation fails, you lose the pointer to original memory, and if you don't have another, you have a memory leak. Correct: `tmp = realloc(array, newSize); if(tmp) { array = tmp; } else { /* error handling */ }`.

Comment: Thanks. The problem was solved, as Mr. Nate Eldredge said. But at the same time, I found another problem. I tried to print the address of result in the strspe while, but it changed in the middle of the operation. So I redistributed the memory the way Mr. Aconcagua said:
char * tmp = realloc(str1, realSize);
if(tmp) {

if(tmp ! = str1){
printf("str1 Address:%p\n",str1);
printf("tmp Address:%p\n",tmp);
}
str1 = tmp;
} else {
//handle
}
. When TMP is not equal to str1, the memory of free str1 is not needed,I tried to free(str1) and got an error

Comment: I think there's only one place in your program where you need to `free()`: at the very end of `main`, you should `free(hello)`.  If `realloc` moves the block of memory, it automatically frees the old one, so you don't need a `free` inside your loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is within this loop:

```
while((argv = va_arg(args,const char *)) && argv != NULL) {
        strcats((char *)result,argv);
}
```

`strcats` reallocates the memory associated to `result` (parameter named `str1`) but `realloc` may change the address. You correctly return the new address but never use it, so `result` never change. Then at a given time, when `realloc` moves the data to another place, the former is no more valid, at the next loop the bad address is then sent again.

Change to :

```
while((argv = va_arg(args,const char *)) && argv != NULL){
        result = strcats(result,argv);
}
```

Comment: Problem solved. But at the same time, I found another problem. I tried to print the address of result in the strspe while, but it changed in the middle of the operation. Char * TMP = realloc(str1, realSize); char * TMP = realloc(str1, realSize); If (tmp) {If (tmp ! Str1){printf("str1 address :%p\n", str1); Printf (" TMP address :% p \ n ", TMP); } str1 = tmp; } else {/ / handle}. When TMP is not equal to str1, how is the data from str1's original address processed? I tried to release (str1) and got an error